# React useEffect() does not display the recently added elements

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I get an error saying that the key in the list should have a unique value, I completely agree with this, the problem arises in another. When I try to create a new object on the client side by means of an asynchronous request to the server, I get an object with the values "undefined", where, accordingly, there is no key itself, since no data has been received. My thought is that most likely the component is rendered earlier than the data is received from the server in the useEffect() hook. But, after forced updating the page, all the data on the page is successfully present.

Component that acts with this data:

```
function NotesList({isModalVisible, onStopNote}) {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await instance.get("/notes");
                setNotes(res.data.notes);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching notes:", error);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);

        }

        fetchData().catch((error) => console.error("Unhandled promise rejection:", error));
    }, []);

    async function addNewNote(data) {
        setIsLoading(true)
        try {
            const res = await instance.post("/notes", data);
            const newNote = res.data
            setNotes((currentNote) => [newNote, ...currentNote])
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error caused during POST", e);
        }
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {isModalVisible && (
                <Modal onHideModal={onStopNote}>
                    <AddNewNote onCancel={onStopNote} onAddNote={addNewNote} />
                </Modal>
            )}{!isLoading && notes.length > 0 && (
            <ul className={classes.notes}>
                {notes.map((note) => {
                        return <Note key={note.id} id={note.id} author={note.author} body={note.body} />;
                })}
            </ul>
            )}
            {!isLoading && notes.length === 0 && (
                <div className={classes.empty}>
                    <h2>No notes have been added yet.</h2>
                    <p>Click on a button to add one.</p>
                </div>
            )}
            {isLoading && (
                <div className={classes.loading}><p>Loading...</p></div>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default NotesList;
```

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: You can keep a check before you are calling setNotes() that the value received from the API is not undefined. And only setNotes when the value is defined.

Comment: `                if (res.data.notes) {
                    setNotes(res.data.notes);
                }` Added this check, didn't affected

Comment: It might be because you are sending an async function as a prop down to your component <AddNewNote>. The result is probably not awaited there?
I think i would rather pass `setNotes` to <AddNewNote> and create the `addNewNote` function there instead. Makes it a bit cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `addNewNote` request-function into your `<AddNewNote>` component then pass `setNotes` to it instead of the previous `addNewNote` function.

Something like this:

```
function NotesList({isModalVisible, onStopNote}) {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await instance.get("/notes");
                setNotes(res.data.notes);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching notes:", error);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);

        }

        fetchData().catch((error) => console.error("Unhandled promise rejection:", error));
    }, []);

   //Removed addNewNote

    return (
        <>
            {isModalVisible && (
                <Modal onHideModal={onStopNote}>
                    <AddNewNote onCancel={onStopNote} setNotes={setNotes} /*new prop*/ />
                </Modal>
```

```
function AddNewNote({onCancel, setNotes}) {
    ...
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    async function addNewNote(data) {
        setIsLoading(true)
        try {
            const res = await instance.post("/notes", data);
            const newNote = res.data
            setNotes((currentNote) => [newNote, ...currentNote])
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error caused during POST", e);
        }
        setIsLoading(false)
    }
...
}
return (
     <button onClick={() => addNewNote(data)} disabled={isLoading}>Add new note</button>
);
```

If this is anything other than practice/homework or something I would consider using [React.Query](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/overview) to do the fetching. Makes it much easier to deal with all the states like loading, errors, results etc.

Comment: Migrated to react-query, thx for advice :)